# Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel - Connecting Microsoft Flows with HTTP request

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, power-automate, secure-gateway

I am a new user for Microsoft Flows.

I have a requirement for Connecting the Microsoft Flow with HTTP Request.

When connecting the HTTP Request, I am using the Client Certificate with the .pfx certificate file.

I am using the below format :

{
    "type": "ClientCertificate",
    "pfx": "aGVsbG8g...d29ybGQ=",
    "password": "myPassword"
}

I am adding the pfx file in Base64 Encoding Format and Password in Plain Text format.

While running the Flow, I get the below error :

```
BadRequest. Http request failed with status code 'SecureChannelFailure' 
and status message: 'The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure 
channel.'.
```

Please help me to resolve this issue and correct the SSL/TLS Secure Channel Error.

Thanks,
:)

Comment: Did you ever solve this one?